# Whats the best way to compare more than two values?

Tags: javascript, compare

I have four divs on my document and I want to execute some code as long as at least two of them have the same text content.

I'm having trouble finding a solution that doesn't include manually comparing each divs text content to every other divs text content

`while(div1.textContent === div2.textContent || div1.textContent === div3.textContent || ....)`

Is there an easy way for doing this?

--edit for HTML

```html
<div class="container">
 <h2>Answers</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md option" id="option1">
      Answer
    </div>
    <div class="col-md option" id="option2">
      Answer
    </div>
    <div class="col-md option" id="option3">
      Answer
    </div>
    <div class="col-md option" id="option4">
      Answer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add HTML too so that it is easy to figure out the problem more properly.

Comment: you can create an `array` them use `.some()`

Answer (score 1):

Save your divs to a unique collection, then create a `Set` of their text content. If the size of the `Set` is less than the length of the collection, there must have been matching content.

```js
test("foo");
test("bar");

function test(cls) {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(`.${cls}`);

  var set = new Set(Array.from(divs, el => el.textContent));

  if (set.size < divs.length) {
    console.log(`'${cls}' found matching content`);
  } else {
    console.log(`'${cls}' did not find matching content`);
  }
}
```

```css
.foo, .bar {
  display: inline-block;
}

.foo {
  color: blue;
}
.bar {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">2</div>
<div class="foo">3</div>
<div class="foo">1</div>
<hr>
<div class="bar">1</div>
<div class="bar">2</div>
<div class="bar">3</div>
<div class="bar">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
const textArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.option'), el => el.innerText);

for(let el of textArray) { 
      const filtered =  textArray.filter(item => item === el);
      if (filtered.length > 1) {
           doSomething();
           break; // can be removed if you want to do continue the loop
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way similar to callback's answer.

Select all elements with their textContent. Filter the textContent by whether 2 or more exist.

```js
//select all elements, getting only their text content
let options = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("option")).map(function(options){
  return options.textContent;
});
//filter by whether 2 or more exist
multipleOptions = options.filter((item, i)=>{
  const iOf = options.indexOf(item);
  return(iOf != i && iOf != -1);//if 2 or more of item, keep it
});
//output..
console.log("number of options with 2 or more of the same text content:", multipleOptions.length);

console.log("boolean, contains 2 or more of the same content?", multipleOptions.length > 0);
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <h2>Answers</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md option" id="option1">
      Answer
    </div>
    <div class="col-md option" id="option2">
      Answer
    </div>
    <div class="col-md option" id="option3">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="col-md option" id="option4">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```